# Parse two files input in for/while loop

Tags: bash, for

I have two files with two different values. I want to run a command in loop which needs input from both file. Let me give the example to make it simple.

File1 contents:

```
google  
yahoo
```

File2 contents:

```
mail  
messenger
```

I need output like the below

```
google is good in mail  
yahoo is good in messenger
```

How can I use a for/while loop to achieve the same?

I need a script to:

$File1 needs to replace first result in File1 and $File2 needs to replace first result in File2

/usr/local/psa/bin/domain --create domain $File1 -mail_service true -service-plan 'Default Domain' -ip 1.2.3.4 -login $File2 -passwd "abcghth"

Comment: Re: your edit. Did you even (try to) read (and understand) my answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard procedure (in Bash) is to read from different file descriptors with the `-u` switch of `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 l1 && IFS= read -r -u4 l2; do
    printf '%s is good in %s\n' "$l1" "$l2"
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

Comment: even without `bash`, `while read <&3; read <&4...done 3<file 4<file` is easily done with any shell.

Comment: @mikeserv True! the question being tagged Bash, I'll keep the answer the way it is. Hopefully your comment will remain here for ever, so that future generations can also have this information! `;)`.

Comment: now I wanna delete it to spite our progeny...

Answer (score 4):

`While loop` is possible but there is easy way

```
paste File{1,2} -d% | sed 's/%/ is good in /'
```

- `%` can be any symbol

But if you insist on loop you can use ones offered by [gniourf_gniourf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28176/gniourf-gniourf) or simply dumb underlined

```
mapfile -t A < File1
mapfile -t B < File2

if [ ${#A[*]} -lt ${#B[*]} ]
then
  L=${#A[*]}
else
  L=${#B[*]}
fi

n=-1
while [ $[++n] -lt $L ]
do
  printf "%s is good in %s\n" "${A[$n]}" "${B[$n]}"
done
```

Comment: You must be sure to choose a symbol that will never appear in the files.

Comment: Your loop answer is one of the ugliest I've ever seen (no offense). If you just want to put the content of a file in an array, please consider using `mapfile` instead; or at least, don't use `eval` since `read` (or even `printf`) will happily set an array field for you. Also, remove the `function` keyword when you're defining a function `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Many thanks for comments. I hadn't use `mapfile` offen so have it fully forgotten.

Comment: You very likely need the `-t` option to `mapfile`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf OK, tested, edited.