# Take the first column from 2 files and write it to a 3rd file

Tags: text-processing

Suppose I have 2 Files, `ABC.txt` & `PQR.txt` with the data shown below as an example:

ABC.txt:

```
ABC DEF
```

PQR.txt:

```
PQR XYZ
```

I want to `grep` column 1 from both files and write into a third text file. How can it be done?

My expected output is (output.txt):

```
ABC PQR
```

Comment: Do you really mean UNIX? What OS are you running? Of the answers here, only the `awk` approach uses non-GNU tools so I am not sure they will work on a UNIX. They all work fine on any Linux.

Answer (score 7):

Here are a couple of ways:

- Using `paste` and `cut` :

  ```
  $ paste -d ' ' <(cut -d' ' -f 1 ABC.txt ) <(cut -d' ' -f 1 PQR.txt ) > output.txt
  ABC PQR
  ```

  If your system does not support process substitution, use this instead:

  ```
  $ cut -d' ' -f 1 ABC.txt > /tmp/aa; cut -d' ' -f 1 PQR.txt > /tmp/bb; paste -d ' ' /tmp/aa /tmp/bb
  ```
- Using `awk` (thanks @Costas):

  ```
  awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1; next}{print a[FNR],$1}' ABC.txt PQR.txt > output.txt
  ```

  The special variable `FNR` is the line number of the current input file and `NR` is the line number of the input in general, whatever file it came from. The two are equal only while the first input file is being read. So, the first fields of the first file are saved in the `a` array (`a[FNR]=$1`) whose keys are line numbers and whose values are the 1st fields. Then, when the second file is reached, we print the value corresponding to its line number (`a[NR]`) and the current line's 1st field.

Answer (score 5):

You can numerate lines by `nl` and use `join`

```
join -o 1.2,2.2 <(nl ABC.txt) <(nl PQR.txt) > OUT.file
```

Or by `cat -n`

```
join -o 1.2,2.2 <(cat -n ABC.txt) <(cat -n PQR.txt) > OUT.file
```

Like [Parse two files input in for/while loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166798/parse-two-files-input-in-for-while-loop) you can use just `bash builtins`

```
while read -u 3 a b && read -u 4 c d
do
  echo "$a $c"
done 3< ABC.txt 4< PQR.txt >OUT.txt
```

Comment: For Join Answer I am getting Error as below ..

ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected

I am using ksh shell

Comment: @RahulPatil **Process Substitution.**
This feature is only available on versions of the UNIX operating system that support the */dev/fd* directory for naming open files. Each command argument of the form `<(list)` or `>(list)` will run process list asynchronously connected to some file in */dev/fd*.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the fields are separated by a single space in the input files, I would write:

```
paste -d " " ABC.txt PQR.txt | cut -d " " -f 1,3 > Output.txt
```

To handle arbitrary whitespace, and more than 2 columns per file, and assuming your shell is bash/ksh/zsh(?)

```
paste -d " " <(awk '{print $1}' ABC.txt) <(awk '{print $1}' PQR.txt) > Output.txt
```

Comment: For First Answer I am getting output as ABC only....

For Second Answer I am getting below Error

ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected

I am using ksh shell

Comment: In the input files, what is the field separator? What version of ksh are you using?